# How to find and replace lines in one file that match the pattern of lines in another file

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, notepad++, find-and-replace

I have a scenario with two documents. The first doc has lines of text, and the second doc also has same text with different text before and after this text. They need to be replaced.

### Doc 1

```
something.nothing.anything="123" 
you.i.him.her="890"
here.there.where="896"
```

### Doc2

```
whathing.whything.anything="ppp" 
moi.pou.yhu.iuh="som"
oh.yuhg.ijuhy.her="khjhu" 
ujg.yhffhjk.iuhjk.pok="090"
adglkn.aergf.ouhj.anything="pora"  
sdf.ujh.ijh.where="asd"
```

### Doc 2 replaced based on only text after last dot(.) and the word in doc 1

```
whathing.whything.anything="123" 
moi.pou.yhu.iuh="som"
oh.yuhg.ijuhy.her="890" 
ujg.yhffhjk.iuhjk.pok="090"
adglkn.aergf.ouhj.anything="pora" 
sdf.ujh.ijh.where="896"
```

How do I achieve this?

Any help will be appreciated. Either in Notepad++ or Excel or another way is fine.

Thanks

Comment: Unclear as to what u want.... Do u want to do find replace operation on doc 1 to make it like doc 2?

Comment: No, i have 3 lines with a certain text at the end. in doc2, multiple lines are there and only some of them have the same ending text as doc 1. I want to find those lines in doc2, (which might not be in order) and replace text in those files only. basically, fidn and replace works for replacing multiple lines with one text . I am looking for replacing multiple lines with corresponding multiple lines in doc 1.Hope that is clear. I actually could not highlight text here. otherwise it would have a little more clearer. thanks